# SharePoint 2007: Site collection deletes itself during restore

Tags: stsadm, restore

I am trying to restore some content databases, and during the restore a sitecollection deletes itself.

I am running the stsadm restore command, and i get the message "No content databases are available for this operation. Createa  content database ..." However, the content database is still there, the webapp is still there. Its the site collection that is missing.

I have recreated it several times and it does the same thing.

I found this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/8668aab4-1ff7-4557-8260-a595f0f192c9

But it did not resolve the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you have another site collection with the same ID (e.g. duplicate copy) in the farm?

This would make it look like the content DB was added etc. but the site collection would not be there.

Comment: I think that was it. Im going to try and retrace my steps and find out what caused this.
It is working now however.